# Accessing a Specific Method in a Specific React Component from a Global Webpack Module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, methods

As you can see in the following code, I want to establish an ajax call in `loadContent()` that called from `ReactComponent`. When accessing child methods, we can use `refs` keyword. However, when the relationship of the caller and the receiver is not parent and child. How can I access the method in react?

### ComponentA

This is a global component that shares its functions to all other react components they need.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class ComponentA {
    loadContent() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxx",
            success: function(data) {
                 // Update the content of ReactComponent.
                 callToThatReactComponent.setContent(data); //Here is the problem
            }
        });
    }
}

var compA = new ComponentA();
export default compA;
```

### ReactCompoment

```
import React from 'react';
import ComponentA from 'path/to/ComponentA';  // The global module

export default class ReactComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ComponentA.loadContent();
    }

    setContent(_content) {
        this.setState({
            content: _content
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to manage state? Redux? If so just dispatch an action and use the lifecycle methods to update state change in the component

Comment: @KeithA - I am using the simplest `setState()` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn Redux and Thunks. Get rid of this global component that you have. You are trying to re-create a state management system like flux or redux but doing it incorrectly.

actions file:

```
const loadContent  = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxx",
            success: function(data) {
                 // Update the content of ReactComponent.
                 dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CONTENT_SUCCESS', data });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

reducers file:

Any function logic that has no side-effects (like api calls or Math.Random()) would go in here.

```
const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOAD_CONTENT_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                action.data
            };
    }
}
```

**any** component file:

Using `mapStateToProps` gives us access to any data from the store.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
    class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return <div>{this.props.data}</div>
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with callback
in ComponentA

```
class ComponentA {
    loadContent( update ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxx",
            success: function(data) {
                 // Update the content.
                 update(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in ReactCompoment:

```
   ComponentA.loadContent( content => {         
                             this.setState({ content: content}) } 
                         );
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I am considering whether there is a method to call a specific method in a specific react component.

Comment: @Casper You would use redux for this and make the method an action creator and a reducer with the function logic in the reducer. You can then call the action creator from anywhere that uses `connect()`.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson - Can you provide a similar example?